# Help with GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, geography

I am trying to get a map with 4 colors, I have several regions with values from 0 to 3 and I want to color those regions with value 0 in white, with value 1 in yellow, with value 2 in orange and with value 3 in red.

I have tried both using `ColorFunction` and `ColorRules` but *Mathematica* ignores these directives. Below are my attempts.
Using `ColorRules`:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Arkansas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Connecticut", "UnitedStates"}] -> 2,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Maryland", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Montana", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewJersey", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ohio", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"RhodeIsland", "UnitedStates"}] -> 2,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Texas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0
  }, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Orange, 3 -> Red}]
```

Using `ColorFunction`:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{White, x == 0}, {Yellow, x == 1}, {Orange, x == 2}, {Red, x == 3}}, 0];
GeoRegionValuePlot[{
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Arkansas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Connecticut", "UnitedStates"}] -> 2,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Maryland", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Montana", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewJersey", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ohio", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"RhodeIsland", "UnitedStates"}] -> 2,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Texas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0
  }, ColorFunction -> f]
```

With `ColorRules`, *Mathematica* ignores the rules and with `ColorFunction` *Mathematica* gives five instances of the error `0 is not a Graphics primitive or directive`. I'm using *Mathematica* 10.4.1.0 on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Here is a minimal example: `GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Texas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0, Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0}, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Blue, 2 -> Orange, 3 -> Red}]` Note that this failure happens when two states are supposed to have the same corresponding color.

Comment: so that's a bug? what about the approach using `ColorFunction`?

Comment: That's easier; try adding `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. (N.B. can somebody with access to multiple versions add the customary header to localize this bug?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is the bug?

It seems that GeoRegionValuePlot will not work correctly when two or more entities have the exact same value.  Consider these examples (and ignore the legend, which is always wrong unless you give an explicit `ColorFunction` as below):

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Arkansas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
   0}, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Purple}]
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Arkansas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
   1}, ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> Purple}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Workaround - make sure that each value is slightly different.

```
valuelist = {Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision", {"Arkansas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}] ->
     0, Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision", {"Connecticut", "UnitedStates"}] -> 2, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
    3, Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision", {"Maryland", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Massachusetts", 
      "UnitedStates"}] -> 3, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Montana", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
    0, Entity[
     "AdministrativeDivision", {"NewJersey", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ohio", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"RhodeIsland", 
      "UnitedStates"}] -> 2, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Texas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0, 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", 
      "UnitedStates"}] -> 0};
colorlist = {0 -> White, 1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Orange, 3 -> Red};
colorlist = valuelist[[All, 2]] /. colorlist;
valuelist[[All, 2]] = # + RandomReal[0.1] & /@ valuelist[[All, 2]];
colorlist = Thread[valuelist[[All, 2]] -> colorlist];
GeoRegionValuePlot[valuelist, ColorRules -> colorlist]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is ugly, but this is the only way I can find to make the `ColorRules` work, and even here the legend doesn't work right.

### Workaround - use a `ColorFunction` instead

This is similar to the code in OP's example, except here we define the `Piecewise` function for all `x` values, which means we get a decent legend,

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{White, x < 1}, {Yellow, 
     1 <= x < 2}, {Orange, 2 <= x < 3}, {Red, 3 <= x < 4}}];
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Arkansas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
   0, Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Connecticut", "UnitedStates"}] -> 2, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Maryland", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
   3, Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}] -> 3,
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Montana", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0,
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewJersey", "UnitedStates"}] -> 
   1, Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ohio", "UnitedStates"}] -> 1,
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"RhodeIsland", 
     "UnitedStates"}] -> 2, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Texas", "UnitedStates"}] -> 0, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"WestVirginia", 
     "UnitedStates"}] -> 0}, ColorFunction -> f, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]